# Which one is better for a beginner to start with game development - unity3d or cryengine 3?

Tags: unity

I am beginner in game development and want to work with either unity or cryengine because they have thier own player and we can play on web also with the player installed. I am confused with which to start. please answer this in terms of flexibity, visibility and speed, which one would be better?

Comment: Unity3d is easier. Unreal Engine or CryEngine is not for a beginner.

Comment: I'm pretty sure cryengine doesn't have a web player.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just start in game development personally don't recommend to begin with a game engine like Unity or Cryengine because they are really complex, with a lot of functionality that may help you or not and like you're starting this will be too much.

Personally for a beginner I recommend to start with the basis so you will understand how a videogame works under the hood like Tetris, then Pacman, and later a scroller where you have to check collisions, physics, projectiles...etc...and after I recommend move on to a 3D engine...

I know that could be a little tedious but it's the best way to start in this industry and it's a path little bit hard but believe me all those little games will help you on the future..

Answer (score 4):

Unity3d is the way to go, between Unity3d or CryEngine3, if you want web based product. CryEngine don't support that.

There is also other options with web support, [NeoAxis Engine](http://www.neoaxis.com) & [Shiva 3d](http://www.stonetrip.com).

Google for more.

**Edit:** The term game development is a huge one. It includes a lot of thing. So, `wanna be a game developer, want suggestion` wont give us any clear idea about what you want to do. It's better if you tell us who/what you already are/can, and what you want to be. *Give us a bigger picture so we can suggest you to fix the details.*

Comment: +1. Unity3d is designed to be easy; CryEngine is not.

Comment: Unity can ALSO be licensed for OTHER platforms. Including smartdevices and consoles.